# Is the surface of an infinitely large sphere a plane?

Tags: geometry, infinity

A pictorial analogy is the difference of the curvature between two points on the surface of a soccer ball and the earth. The curvature on the surface of the soccer ball is immediately noticeable, whereas this isn't the case when you're looking around in a wide, flat region with no hills and mountains on the earth's surface.

In a bit more mathematical terms let $r$ be the radius sphere and the curvature be defined as $\frac 1 r$. With $\lim_{r \to \infty} \frac 1 r$ the sphere becomes infinitely large such that the curvature converges to 0.

Does this mean that under this circumstances a sphere becomes a plane, or is my intuition just wrong?

Comment: This depends on your definitions.

Comment: Depends whether you take a local or a global view. The local view is: if you are standing on some point of the sphere, then the horizon is (asympotically) flat, i.e. no difference from standing on a plane, for any given distance around you.  The global view is: it is and remains a large   sphere. For example, the function of the surface area  depending on the  radius never changes.

Comment: Well, it's not obvious that a sphere of radius $r>M$ for all $M\in \mathbf{R}$ even exists as a set. In some sense, though, you do have the right intuition. A sphere is locally Euclidean in the sense that if you have points that are close enough together you can "pretend" you are in a Euclidean/flat space.

Comment: The distinction between a local and global point of view is a subtle detail that could have avoided my wrong intuition in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a sphere $S_R$ of radius $R>0$ in ${\mathbb R}^3$ touching the $(x,y)$-plane from above at $(0,0,0)$. The equation of this sphere is
$$x^2+y^2+(z-R)^2=R^2\ .$$
Solving for $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$ and taking the solution  giving $z=0$ at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ we obtain
$$z={x^2+y^2\over R+\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}={x^2+y^2\over 2R}+{\rm higher \ order\ terms}\ .$$
It follows that $z=0$ is a fine approximation to the spherical surface near $(x,y)=(0,0)$ when $R\gg1$.

Answer (score 1):

You are right; a sphere is a differentiable manifold. Rather than take the radius to $\infty$, take the radius of your neighborhood to $0$. There is a diffeomorphism from a small neighborhood of a point on the sphere with the unit disc in $\Bbb{R}^2$, and in the limit that diffeomorphism approaches an isometry.